# extracting certain letters from a a unique code in each row in R, with tidyverse only

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to extract the last numbers from a unique code, in each row. I do not know how to pursue this task, with tidyverse only, in R

here is an example:

```
structure(list(`CCGCode` = c("E38000232", "E38000237", 
"E38000004", "E38000240", "E38000006", "E38000007"), Total = c(17, 
27, 27, 43, 30, 42)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

By spotting the CCGCode in the data frame above you'll see the code in each row. I want to create a new column with ccg that takes only the last three digits of that code. For example, we have `E38000006` in CCGCode and want into the new column ccg only the `006` because does are the last digits. How to do this.

Comment: i don't know the tidyverse solution, but you can use `gsub('(...)$|.', '\\1', CCGCode)` or if all the codes are 10 characters long `substr(CCGCode, 7, 10)`

Comment: Another alternative `df %>% mutate(code = stringr::str_trunc(CCGCode, width = 3, side = "left", ellipsis = ""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple ways to do this which produce slightly different end results, hopefully one of them is along the lines of what you're looking for.

**Method 1**

```
df %>% 
  separate(CCGCode, c("CCGCode", "Last_3"), sep = -3)
```

**Method 2**

```
str_sub(df$CCGCode, -3) %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  select(CCGCode, "Last_3" = value, Total)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number at the end of the CCGCode you could use `gsub` from base. If you need something from tidyverse, perhaps write code with a `%>%` pipe symbol. Try this:

```
#Assigning your example to df
df <-structure(list(`CCGCode` = c("E38000232", "E38000237", 
"E38000004", "E38000240", "E38000006", "E38000007"), Total = c(17, 
27, 27, 43, 30, 42)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#gsub removes beginning of CCG code and assigns to df$new_col
df$CCGCode %>% gsub("E38000", "",.) ->df$new_col
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str_sub()` in `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(code = str_sub(CCGCode, -3))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   CCGCode   Total code 
#   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
# 1 E38000232    17 232  
# 2 E38000237    27 237  
# 3 E38000004    27 004  
# 4 E38000240    43 240  
# 5 E38000006    30 006  
# 6 E38000007    42 007
```

or using `word()`(also in `stringr`)

```
df %>%
  mutate(code = word(CCGCode, -3, -1, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)"))
```

Comment: I am sorry, the previous person did answer. But your code is more elegant. I have gave Chad S because he was the first, he is also new the the stack overflow and indeed it worked. Also, I want to encourage him as he is new.  However, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach using **tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(CCGCode = c("E38000232", "E38000237", "E38000004", "E38000240", "E38000006", "E38000007"), 
                 Total = c(17, 27, 27, 43, 30, 42))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(CCG = str_extract(CCGCode, regex("\\d{3}$")))
#     CCGCode Total CCG
# 1 E38000232    17 232
# 2 E38000237    27 237
# 3 E38000004    27 004
# 4 E38000240    43 240
# 5 E38000006    30 006
# 6 E38000007    42 007
```

Comment: thank you. it worked yes I suppose to be fair to the first who answered. Thank you. Your is really nice as it is applicable to so many other problems!

Comment: Yeah. It's my pleasure! We have a bunch of solutions. Just use whatever it serves best for you.